# Find the common ratio of the geometric series with the sum and the first term

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given: 
Geometric Series Sum ($S_n$) = 39
First Term ($a_1$) = 3
number of terms ($n$) = 3

Find the common ratio $r$.

*I have been made aware that the the common ratio is 3, but for anyone trying to solve this, don't plug it in as an answer the prove that it's true. Try to find it without using it.

Comment: The solutions for this restricted problem are $r=3$ and $r=-4$. Just need to solve $1+r+r^2=13$. Sum of geometric formula is not useful here.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I am very sure that the sum is correct and it should be included. (Sorry for unclear explanations)

Comment: I meant that to solve this problem, you do not need the formula $a\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$ for the sum of the GP $a+ar+\cdots +ar^{n-1}$. Since there are only $3$ terms, want $3+3r+3r^2=39$, which simplifies to $r^2+r-12=0$. A nice quadratic, it even factors.

Comment: 3,-12,48 works as does 3,9,27 so there are a pair of answers here.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an *infinite* geometric series with first term $a$ and common ratio $r$ (with $|r|\lt1$) then the sum $s$ is $$s={a\over1-r}$$

In your problem, you know $s$ and $a$ --- can you solve for $r$?

EDIT: OP has clarified that the number of terms is $3$.

That means the terms are $3$, $3r$, and $3r^2$. And they add up to $39$. So --- can you work out $r$ from this information?

Comment: Yes, I need the formula and how did you create that formula from the original geometric series formula.

Comment: @clixbrigidxterx:  If $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the ratio, you have $a(1+r+r^2)=39$.  It seems likely that $a,r$ are integers, so factor $39$ and try them all.  There aren't many.

Comment: @clixbrigidxterx: if you know $r=3$ what is $1+r+r^2$?  What do you know, it divides into $39$

Comment: @clixbrigidxterx Or you can compute the roots of the quadratic.

Comment: @clixbrigidxterx did you need to construct the formula from scratch or do you just need to solve for r? I think Gerry explained it pretty well. Your first term is a, second term is the first term multiplied by r (ar), third term is the second multiplied by r ($ar^2$) etc. It's a good exercise to check that the formula from my answer holds for finite geometric series, and the formula Gerry wrote for his holds for infinite geometric series

Comment: @Ross Millikan, I want to use the formula. That is why I include the answer in the last paragraph. I just guessed and use my common sense. I just need someone who can show me how can I find the common ratio using the formula like "user6228" used.

Comment: @user62228, I only need the common ratio. I need the formula and the process on how to find the ratio.

Comment: clix, I don't know what you mean by "the formula", but between my answer and the comment by @user62228 we have shown you the process for finding the common ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You have $a+ar+ar^2=39$.  Do you understand how this comes from what you asked?  Then $a\frac  {r^3-1}{r-1}=39$ as shown in [Wikipedia on geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).  Given that $r=3$, we get $a\frac {26}2=39$ so $a=3$ and we have $3+9+27=39$.

Comment: I want to see the process it gone through. Please, do not use the answer (common ratio) to substitute $r$. I only include this answer so you can prove that the answer is 3.

Comment: @clixbrigidxterx:  See André Nicolas' comment.  He has it very simply for a 3 term progression.  Then JB King solves the quadratic.  For more general problems, you need to read on geometric progressions, which derive the sum of the series formula that we have all quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Finite progression with $\,n\,$ elements:

$$39=S_n=3\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}\Longrightarrow \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}=13\ldots\text{we need to know}\,\,\,n$$

Infinite descending geometric series:

$$39=S=\frac{3}{1-q}\Longrightarrow 1-q=\frac{1}{13}\Longrightarrow q=\frac{12}{13}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have the formula 
$$S_n=\frac{a*(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$
In your case, n=3, a=3 and $S_n$=39. Now solve for r.

Comment: @user6228, can you make show me how can I do it? I am stuck of finding the ratio in the formula because of exponents and some factors.

Comment: @clixbrigidxterx does my solution work? I know it's a bit outdated, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The genreal sum formula in geometric sequences: $$S_n=\frac{a_1\left(r^n-1\right)}{r-1}$$ In your case, $S_n=39$, $a_1=3$, $n=3$. Now you just need to find $r$:

$$39=\frac{3\left(r^3-1\right)}{r-1}$$ $$\ 13=\frac{r^3-1}{r-1}$$ $$\ 13\left(r-1\right)=r^3-1$$ $$\ 13r-13=r^3-1$$ $$\ r^3-13r+12=0$$
$$\ r_1=-4,\ r_2=3,\ r_3=1$$

Since you said it's a geometric series, $r ≠ 1$, but even if it did, plugging it back in would give you $3 + 3 + 3 ≠ 39$. So, the common ratio is $$r = 3, -4$$ Plug $r=3$ back into the formula and see that it works. As for $r=-4$, you'll have to do it the long way because it won't work in the sum formula, so you could just write that $3 + (-12) + 48 = 39$ which is indeed true.

Answer (score 0):

Any way one can find the ratio, r, for higher powers i.e. where n=12, a1 =80 and the sum is 1200.